# Como recuperar una consulta con dapper en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un proyecto de escritorio en VB.NET, con VS2019, instale Dapper, para recuperar los registros, pero no he podido hacer que me regrese todos los campos del select solo me devuelve el primer campo de la consulta, con sus registros, pero no toda la consulta, les dejo mi codigo si me pueden dar una guia o que debo modificar, no uso una clase por que quiero un SELECT sencillo.

```
Private Sub mpLlenarDataConDapper()
    Using aoConnection As New SqlConnection(Cnx.ConnectionString)
        
        aoConnection.Open()

        Dim aoLst As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        
        aoLst = aoConnection.Query(Of String)(" SELECT IDECIA, RZNSOC, DSCCIA, DIRECC, TELEFO
            ,NUMFAX  ,PAGWEB, CIUDAD, URLLOG, NUMRUC FROM CNF.MSTCIA ").ToList()                       

        GridControl1.DataSource = aoLst

    End Using
End Sub
```

Me devuelve solo el Campo IDECIA con sus registros correctos, pero no el resto de campos.

Saludos

Me devolvio datos la consulta, de la siguiente manera:

```
Dim aListaActivos = aoConnection.Query("SELECT IDEPSNAL, IDECIA, IDCODEMP, NOMPRI, NOMSEG, APEPRI, APESEG, NUMCEDULA, NUMSEGSOC FROM [PLA].[MSTPSNAL] WHERE IDECIA = 1")
                GridControl1.DataSource = aListaActivos.ToList()
```

Hasta alli bien, pero si no especifico las columnas en el grid, me duplica el registro hacia la derecha, puedo espficicar las columnas pero normalmente lo mando a llenar con data table y no me da este problema, mira la imagen por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que estás casteando la query a String. Prueba a quitar `Of String` de la `Query` y debería devolverte un `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: Pikoh, hice una modificacion, pero me quedo esa duda que postee, saludos